# How many results in these two programs and why?

Tags: java

```
//Number 1
    int x = 2;
    while (x < 200) {
        System.out.println(x + " ");
        x *= x;
```

**Output**: 3

```
//Number 2
    String word = "a";
    while (word.length() < 10) {
        word = "b" + word + "b";
    }

    System.out.println(word);
```

**Output**: bbbbbabbbbb

Number 1: Why is the output 3? I'm doing 2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 128. Therefore, I think the answer should be 7?

Number 2: What happened there? And is the result "zero" or "infinity" or "unknown" or a number? Why?

Comment: for number 1, it's not multiplying by 2, it's squaring the number 2*2 -> 4*4 -> 16*16

Comment: Number 1; output = "2 ", "4 ", 16 "  that is 3 results // Number 2: output = "bbbbbabbbbb", that is **1 result**  ((considering one result as one value/line output))

Comment: @user85421 number 2 has 5 results

Comment: How that? output is only one line, only one word, there is only one output command, maybe 11 letters; why 5 results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Number#1 you are not multiplying by a factor of `2` but instead you are mutiplying `x` by the power of `x`

```
iteration #0 - x = 2
iteration #1 - x = 4
iteration #2 - x = 16
iteration #3 - x = 256
```

change `x *= x;` to `x *= 2;`

For Number#2 just use a debugger to see what you are actually doing:

```
iteration #1 - word = "bab";
iteration #2 - word = "bbabb";
iteration #3 - word = "bbbabbb";
iteration #4 - word = "bbbbabbbb";
iteration #5 - word = "bbbbbabbbbb";
```

`word`'s length now is greater than 10, so it stops

Comment: Thanks for number2 but I still don't understand number 1..
EDIT: Nevermind. I get it. 2x2 = 4 -> 4x4 = 16 -> 16*16 = 256. THANKS